# New to illustrator but trying to draw a wireframe/UX flow chart

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I've been developing an iOS app lately and realized how important designing a UX flow chart would be. However, I'm struggling trying to figure out how to get started. I run across a lot of these on pinterest, but absolutely no information on how to get started.

For example:
[image]

Adobe Illustrator has templates for iPhone 6s wireframe kits, but it seems to me that it's just simply designing the interfaces and not necessarily representing a flow chart like in this picture.

Am I just simply using the wrong product (it's part of my CC subscription so figured I'd give it a shot), or am I just not understanding how to make the connections here? Is looking for tutorials on iPhone app UX flowcharts and wireframe not the right area to be researching?

Comment: Connections are just lines, are you asking how to draw lines?

Comment: It seems more like a line than a connection. If I use the iPhone 6s webframe kit and draw a line between the side of one wireframed page to the next, and then move the page, the "connections" don't move with it. The line remains stationary and I have to move it manually. It doesn't seem to have a connection like they would in Visio for example. I'm trying to convert a wireframe project to a flowchart.

Comment: Illustrator on't make actual "connections". It just doesn't work that way. So, yes, you'd have to manually adjust the connection lines after moving things.

Comment: Illustrator wasn't designed for that purpose.  There is a rather nice online flow chart creator here: https://www.draw.io/ or if you want something you can run on your computer, LibreOffice Draw has reasonable flow chart capabilities with connectors.

Comment: @LewlSauce illustrator is a direct modeling tool. It does not do this kind of thing you draw lines if you move then then you either modify your lines or move them. No automation like this, that's what it means to be a direct modeling tool. You gain flexibility to do whatever you want at the cost of automation. ALL in all its not a terrible benefit to automate the lines, you save around 10 seconds per connection. At 12 connections per drawing it takes you 390 drawings recuperate the time you spent on this question.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks so much guys! I seriously appreciate the information here

Comment: Have you checked other wireframing online services like Cacoo? I actually use it sometimes not only for wireframing but also untangling difficult charts. Then I take a screenshot and make it look pretty in Illustrator,

Answer (score 0):

By using illustrator u can only show the UI.
if you want to show the working flow of your app, then u can go for Adobe Experience Design (XD). Here you can directly import your app designs from illustrator to adobe XD and you can show the flow of your app.

If you want some templates regarding wireframing for an ios app, then search on google or here is a link, it might be helpful.

https://speckyboy.com/free-wireframe-templates-mobile-app-web-ux-design/

And remember one thing, if you want to make a prototype then first make the rough flow chart on a piece of paper. Then draw the wireframe of your app in different artboards and combine all wireframes in a single artboard by drawing connection lines and then simply import your ai files to any prototype software like Adobe xd, Justinmind, InVision for showing the working flow of your app.